# I don't know if my variables are not being initialized or something else

Tags: c++, qt

So, after debugging the program in Qt I realized that the debugger thinks I did not initialized the variables; however, I got the variables in and out from the private class, made the class a pointer and seems like nothing happens. Please let me know what am I missing, I have the same problem in other program but I don't know if is just me or the program.

The code is as follows:

main:

```
#include "selectionarea.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // QMainWindow *win = new QMainWindow();

     QSize winsize(500,500);
     SelectionArea area;

     area.setStartingLocX(0);
     area.setStartingLocY(0);
     area.setLength(300);
     area.setWidth(300);


     area.resize(winsize);
     area.show();


     return app.exec();
 }
```

selectionarea.cpp

```
#include "selectionarea.h"
#include <QPainter>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QLabel>


SelectionArea::SelectionArea()
{


}

void SelectionArea::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{

    QRect rectangle(getStartingLocx(), getStartingLocy(),
                     getWidth(), getLength());

    /*QRegion Constructs a paint event object with the
     * region that needs to be updated. The region is
     * specified by paintRegion.*/

    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::SolidPattern,
                        2.0,
                        Qt::SolidLine,
                        Qt::FlatCap,
                        Qt::MiterJoin));
    painter.drawRect(rectangle);

}

void SelectionArea::setStartingLocX(int x)
{
    x=StartingLocX;
    qDebug() <<x<<" "<<StartingLocX;

}
int SelectionArea::getStartingLocx()
{
     return StartingLocX;
}

void SelectionArea::setStartingLocY(int y)
{
    y=StartingLocY;
     qDebug() <<y<<" "<<StartingLocY;
}

int SelectionArea::getStartingLocy()
{
     return StartingLocY;
}

void SelectionArea::setWidth(int w)
{
    w=Width;
    qDebug() <<w<<" "<<Width;
}

int SelectionArea::getWidth()
{
    return Width;
}

void SelectionArea::setLength(int l)
{
    l=Length;
}

int SelectionArea::getLength()
{
    return Length;
}
```

and selectionarea.h

```
#ifndef SELECTIONAREA_H
#define SELECTIONAREA_H

#include <QPixmap>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QRect>

class SelectionArea : public QLabel
{
    int StartingLocX;
    int StartingLocY;
    int Length;
    int Width;

public:

    SelectionArea();
    ~SelectionArea()
    {

    }

    void setStartingLocX(int);
    void setStartingLocY(int);
    void setLength(int);
    void setWidth(int);

    int getStartingLocx();
    int getStartingLocy();
    int getWidth();
    int getLength();

    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);



};

#endif // SELECTIONAREA_H
```

forgive my ambiguity.

UPDATE:
the application output is 
0  0
0  0
0  0

and the window is displayed.

Comment: You really are looking for [`QRubberBand`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrubberband.html). Use that and be done. The documentation has examples of handling mouse events to get typical behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Making my comment the answer*

Your setter function should actually look like:

```
void SelectionArea::setStartingLocX(int x)
{
    StartingLocX = x;
}
```

because you initialize class member variable `StartingLocX` with the value of `x` (same for other setter functions). In your version of the function you do the opposite, so that your class member variables remain uninitialized.

Comment: Thank you! the order actually meant nothing to me until now.

Answer (score 1):

You don't initialize the member variables when creating an instance of `SelectionArea`. You only set them afterwards via the setter functions.

You should initialize them in your constructor using an *initializer list*.

This might in this case be obsolete, yet it will prevent you from running into strange error cases.

Comment: Can you please provide an example, I am a very visual person.
I think I understand what you are saying, but I wanna make sure.

Comment: @MicroVirus Not true. If you don't provide an initializer list only objects are default initialized (if they provide a default ctor). Pointers and other primitives are still unitialized. References and objects w/o default ctor need to be initialized via init list (at least pre C++11)

Answer (score 0):

This is very much non-idiomatic C++:

```
SelectionArea area;
area.setStartingLocX(0);
area.setStartingLocY(0);
area.setLength(300);
area.setWidth(300);
```

You should refactor the code to read:

```
SelectionArea area{0, 0, 300, 300};
```

or even

```
SelectionArea area{300, 300};
```

Furthermore, you really should make it a true `QObject`, not a half-made one. And don't shadow `QWidget`'s own members (like `witdth()` etc.) with your own of similar names. Getters don't have to have a `get` prefix, it only adds to visual clutter and is not helpful.

The properties I've added below are likely overkill, just add the ones you're reasonably likely to use. It's still a good idea to simply keep the entire selection as a `QRect` - that's what it really is.

```
class SelectionArea : public QLabel
{
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(QRect selection READ selection WRITE setSelection USER true)
  Q_PROPERTY(QPoint selTopLeft READ selTopLeft WRITE setSelTopLeft STORED false)
  Q_PROPERTY(int selX READ selX WRITE setSelX STORED false)
  Q_PROPERTY(int selY READ sely WRITE setSelY STORED false)        
  Q_PROPERTY(QSize selSize READ selSize WRITE setSelSize STORED false)
  Q_PROPERTY(int selWidth READ selWidth WRITE setSelWidth STORED false)
  Q_PROPERTY(int selHeight READ selHeight WRITE setSelHeight STORED false)
  QRect m_selection;
public:
  SelectionArea(QWidget * parent = 0) : QLabel(parent) {}
  SelectionArea(const QSize & size, QWidget * parent = 0) :
    QLabel(parent), m_selection(QPoint(), size) {}
  SelectionArea(const QPoint & startingLoc, const QSize & size, 
                QWidget * parent = 0) :
    QLabel(parent), m_selection(startingLoc, size) {}
  SelectionArea(int width, int height, QWidget * parent = 0) :
    QLabel(parent), m_selection(0, 0, width, height) {}
  SelectionArea(int x, int y, int width, int height, QWidget * parent = 0) :
    QLabel(parent), m_selection(x, y, width, height) {}

  void setSelection(const QRect & r) {
    if (m_selection == r) return;
    m_selection = r;
    update();
  }
  void setSelTopLeft(const QPoint & p) {
    if (m_selection.topLeft() == p) return; 
    m_selection.moveTo(p);
    update();
  }
  void setSelX(int x) {
    if (m_selection.x() == x) return;
    m_selection.moveTo(x, m_selection.y());
    update(); 
  }
  void setSelY(int y) {
    if (m_selection.y() == y) return;
    m_selection.moveTo(m_selection.x(), y);
    update(); 
  }
  void setSelSize(const QSize & s) {
    if (m_selection.size() == s) return;
    m_selection.setSize(s);
    update();
  }
  // etc.

  QRect selection() const { return m_selection; }
  QPoint selTopLeft() const { return m_selection.topLeft(); }
  int selX() const { return m_selection.x(); }
  int selY() const { return m_selection.y(); }
  QSize selSize() const { return m_selection.size(); }
  // etc.

protected:
  void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
};
```

It's also questionable whether you really want to derive from `QLabel`. It seems that you override the painting, and you don't really care for the `text` property directly. You'd be better off inheriting straight from a `QFrame` instead.

Comment: You my friend, do write a lot. I did got it working, but you do bring some very advantageous ideas. I am only interested on drawing a rectangle that can select some region, Qframe might be very helpful however since I need this rectangle to select some amount of pixels in a picture Qpaint seems appropriate; however, I am going to study QFrame more closely, it might be more beneficial. ;)

Comment: @JoseL.Rico You don't need any custom properties at all if you're using the widget directly as a means of selection (I thought it was used to display some text). Simply change the widget's `geometry`. It'd be fairly trivial to do it on top of a `QFrame`. You only need to override mouse press/release/move events to resize and move the widget.

Comment: Yea, and there I am. I am using moseMoveEvent, but it is twisting my brain right now. I guess the problem lays on my inexperience playing with classes and idiotic pointers.

Comment: @JoseL.Rico Pointers are not idiotic. They have reasonably simple meaning (semantics). They work more or less like street addresses: you can modify them, but end up an address that points at an empty lot; you can have an old address that pointed to a friend's home but now there's a shopping mall there, you can also make up completely bogus addresses and try using it, with ill effects :)

Comment: The concept is easy, their implementation however.... It is not a walk in the park